# WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW in alt-tab

Tags: c++, mfc

i would like to have a `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` window appear in <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, or a normal window to have the same look as a toolwindow.

is this at all possible ? ;/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at ITaskbarList::AddTab. The URL is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774652(v=vs.85).aspx